# C# DateTime Parse inconsistency

Tags: c#, datetime, timezone, datetime-format, invariantculture

I´ve got a question about DateTime
My Code is:

```
DateTime.ParseExact("2018-06-13T12:05:55.7738391Z", "yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:ss.fffffffZ", System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture).ToString("yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:ss.fffffffZ")
```

The result is:

```
"2018-06-13T14:05:55.7738391Z"
```

Why does the DateTime add 2 hourse? (I tried with ...00:05:55...)
And how do I prevent this?

Comment: It will likely be a time zone issue.

Comment: Try it with `.ToUniversalTime()` before the `ToString`.

Comment: Other option is to use styles, eg. `DateTimeStyles.AdjustToUniversal` in `ParseExact()`. One thing to fix would be the format, at the end you should have *K* for kind, not *Z*, unless you actually assume that date-time will by only UTC.

Comment: Preferably, `DateTimeStyles.RoundTripKind` would be better, since the `Z` maps to `DateTimeKind.Utc` nicely.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My guess would be you are in a time zone of UTC+2.

```
var time = DateTime.ParseExact("2018-06-13T12:05:55.7738391Z", "yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:ss.fffffffZ", System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);

Console.WriteLine(time.ToLocalTime().ToString("yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:ss.fffffffZ"); // + 2 hours ?   
Console.WriteLine(time.ToUniversalTime().ToString("yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:ss.fffffffZ"); // +0 hours ?
```

You have said the time is UTC (Z = zulu time = UTC+0), but the timezone of your computer is automatically adding 2 hours.

--

And to be totally correct, you should use `time.ToString("o");`.  You are confusing matters because your `ToString` contains a trailing Z, which is not added by the formatter but just copied into the output.